# How to construct a string from letters of each word from list?

Tags: python, loops

I am wondering how to construct a string, which takes 1st letter of each word from list. Then it takes 2nd letter from each word etc.
For example :
Input --> my_list = ['good', 'bad', 'father']
Every word has different length (but the words in the list could have equal length)
The output should be: 'gbfoaaodtdher'.

I tried:

```
def letters(my_list):
    string = ''

    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        for j in range(len(my_list)):
            string += my_list[j][i]

    return string

print(letters(['good', 'bad', 'father']))
```

and I got:
'gbfoaaodt'.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good job for [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

s = ''.join([c for x in zip_longest(*my_list) for c in x if c])
print(s)
```

Or [`more_itertools.interleave_longest`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_longest):

```
from more_itertools import interleave_longest

s = ''.join(interleave_longest(*my_list))
print(s)
```

Output: `gbfoaaodtdher`

Used input:

```
my_list = ['good', 'bad', 'father']
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @mozway is the best approach, but if you want to go along with your original method, this is how

```python
def letters(my_list):
    string = ''

    max_len = max([len(s) for s in my_list])

    for i in range(max_len):
        for j in range(len(my_list)):
            if i < len(my_list[j]):
                string += my_list[j][i]

    return string

print(letters(['good', 'bad', 'father']))
```

Output: `gbfoaaodtdher`

Answer (score 0):

We can do without zip_longest as well:

```
l = ['good', 'bad', 'father']
longest_string=max(l,key=len)
''.join(''.join([e[i] for e in l if len(e) > i]) for i in range(len(longest_string)))

#'gbfoaaodtdher'
```